# Is it possible to read an Access DB while it has a file lock?

Tags: java, database, windows, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I am trying to read a backend access database from another program using java. However when the other program is running it appears to have a wirte/read lock on the file.

This gives me this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: testdb.mdb (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.openChannel(DatabaseImpl.java:474)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:372)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:170)
```

Is it possible to read the database file while the other program has a read/write lock on it?

Comment: Are you going through a data access layer/driver? `.RandomAccessFile.open` looks like your trying to open the file directly, if so what do you expect to do with it?

Comment: I'm using a java library called [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) to access the database.